# didDiscoverPeripheral method not calling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

We are developing bluetooth iOS app.First we need nearest bluetooth devices `names`,Place into `uitableView`.So we using `corebluetooth.framework`.Tried like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.peripherals=[NSMutableArray new];
    NSDictionary *scanOptions = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)};
    NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"F3501201-3F04-4744-BE91-154BB7D51BDC"]];

    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

}
-(void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Discovered peripheral %@",peripheral.identifier.UUIDString);
     NSLog(@"Discovered peripheral %@",peripheral.name);
    [self.peripherals addObject:peripheral];
    [central connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

}
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    switch (central.state)
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
        {
            NSLog(@"State: Unsupported");
        } break;

        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
        {
            NSLog(@"State: Unauthorized");
        } break;

        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        {
            NSLog(@"State: Powered Off");
        } break;

        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        {
            NSLog(@"State: Powered On");
            [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:scanOptions];
        } break;

        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        {
            NSLog(@"State: Unknown");
        } break;

        default:
        {
        }

    }
}
```

We got **State: Powered On**.But didDiscoverPeripheral  method never called.We are new to this.We need When my app is open all bluetooth device placed into UItableView ,then we click on specific Devices.What Wrong in my code Please guide to us.

Comment: Remove the `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` for `viewDidLoad’ - you can only start savnning once the central is in the powered on state

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for reply.We tried as you said.but no luck Please guide to us.we are working on last 2days but we get nothing

Comment: Have you tried the LightBlue app from the App Store to make sure your peripheral is visible?

Comment: @Paulw11 We need Peripheral devices name visible in UITableview and then click any Device that Devices pair with my Devices.So we need first devices names Places into UITableView.Please guide to us We are not tried LightBlue

Comment: Your code looks ok aside from the misplaced scan... That is why I suggest you try LightBlue to confirm that your peripheral is BLE and advertising.

Comment: I also have a sample app here https://github.com/paulw11/BTBackground

Comment: @Paul11 thanks for link .We flowed you code .We are run code in  phone4s and ipad 2.But We don't get any Devices names.-(void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            [self startScan];
            break;
    }
}
if bluetooth is on.Then start Scan but Never called this method  didDiscoverPeripheral
Please help to us

Comment: Are you sure that your peripheral is a Bluetooth Low Energy device?  What is it?

Comment: @Paulw11 My devices IPhone4s (IOS 8.4.1) and iPad 2 (IOS 8.3)

Comment: Yes, but what device are you trying to discover? If you want to discover the other iOS device then you need to run an app to advertise a service - LightBlue can do this if you don't want to write code

Comment: @Paulw11 We need not only IOS we need Enable bluetooth devices names ,Please tell me first using LightBlue can get other OS devices name or not ?

Comment: The first step is to get your code to detect a device. Your code should do that if the device is advertising. My code certainly does. Once you have discovered a device you can get its name if it advertises one. LightBlue is just a convenient app for testing device discovery and advertising simulated devices

Answer (score 2):

Try giving this while you are scanning for all devices.

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];

 [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

Once you get list of devices at `didDiscoverPeripheral delegate` method, find the correct service UUID by calling `discoverServices:nil` in your Peripheral. so you can scan for peripherals with correct service UUID.

(or) you can use https://github.com/l0gg3r/LGBluetooth

all you need to do is,

```
[[LGCentralManager sharedInstance] scanForPeripheralsByInterval:5
                                                         completion:^(NSArray *peripherals) {
     }];
```